# Groovy - how to match (assert) that a certain value is contained in an array of expected values

Tags: groovy, assert, matcher, hamcrest

I have a script which checks returned http status codes.

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.anyOf
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat

int[] expectedStatuses = [201,204]
def pollStatusCode = 202
def actualStatusCode = 201
```

How to assert that actualStatusCode is contained in an array of expectedStatuses' values? Something like:

```
assertThat(actualStatusCode, anyOf(equalTo(pollStatusCode), equalTo(expectedStatuses)))
```

Is there any way how to assert this type of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
assert actualStatusCode in expectedStatuses
```

or

```
assert expectedStatuses.contains(actualStatusCode)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was kind of blind with that assertThat thing and didn't think about the other options.